# how to display per 2 items of all data with many different divs using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to display 3 items per div, with many divs different from the action click on link load more.
my code as below:

```
<div class="wadah" id="list_1">
    <a href="" class="wadah__item" id="list_item_1_1">
        aaa
    </a>

    <a href="" class="wadah__item" id="list_item_1_2">
        bbb
    </a>
    <a href="" class="wadah__item" id="list_item_1_3">
        ccc
    </a>
    <a href="" class="wadah__item" id="list_item_1_4">
        ddd
    </a>
    <a href="" class="wadah__item" id="list_item_1_5">
        eee
    </a>
    <a href="" class="wadah__item" id="list_item_1_6">
        fff
    </a>
    <div id="loadMore" class="LoadMore">Load more 1</div>
</div>

<div class="wadah" id="list_2">
    <a href="" class="wadah__item" id="list_item_2_1">
        2_a
    </a>

    <a href="" class="wadah__item" id="list_item_2_2">
        2_b
    </a>
    <a href="" class="wadah__item" id="list_item_2_3">
        2_c
    </a>
    <a href="" class="wadah__item" id="list_item_2_4">
        2_d
    </a>
    <a href="" class="wadah__item" id="list_item_2_5">
        2_e
    </a>
    <a href="" class="wadah__item" id="list_item_2_6">
        2_f
    </a>

    <div id="loadMore" class="LoadMore">Load more 2</div>
</div>
```

javascipt code:

```
$(function () {
  $(".wadah__item").slice(0, 2).slideDown().css('display', 'flex');
  $(".LoadMore").on('click', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      $(".wadah__item:hidden").slice(0, 2).slideDown().css('display', 'flex');

      if ($(".wadah__item:hidden").length == 0) {
          $(".LoadMore").fadeOut('slow');
      }

      $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: $(this).offset().top
      }, 2000);
  });
});
```

I want every link load more to be clicked, then the item that appears is 2 from each div.

Link Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/mrcrabs/5g9uao73/13/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to filter out `wadah__item` elements based on the clicked element. So get the parent of the clicked element and get hidden elements within that. To get first `2` child you can use [`:nth-child()` pseudo-class selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) with formula `-n + 2` ( selects 2nd and 1st child).

```
$(function() {
  $(".wadah .wadah__item:nth-child(-n + 2)").slideDown().css('display', 'flex');
  $(".LoadMore").on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $(this).parent().find(".wadah__item:hidden").slice(0, 2).slideDown().css('display', 'flex');

    if ($(this).parent().find(".wadah__item:hidden").length == 0) {
      $(this).fadeOut('slow');
    }

    $('html,body').animate({
      scrollTop: $(this).offset().top
    }, 2000);
  });
});
```

```js
$(function() {

  $(".wadah .wadah__item:nth-child(-n + 2)").slideDown().css('display', 'flex');
  $(".LoadMore").on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $(this).parent().find(".wadah__item:hidden").slice(0, 2).slideDown().css('display', 'flex');

    if ($(this).parent().find(".wadah__item:hidden").length == 0) {
      $(this).fadeOut('slow');
    }

    $('html,body').animate({
      scrollTop: $(this).offset().top
    }, 2000);
  });
});
```

```css
.wadah {
  margin: 30px 0;
}

.wadah__item {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-top: none;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.wadah__item {
  display: none;
}

#loadMore {
  color: green;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#loadMore:hover {
  color: black;
}

#showLess {
  color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
}

#showLess:hover {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wadah" id="list_1">
    <a href="" class="wadah__item" id="list_item_1_1">
    aaa
   </a>

    <a href="" class="wadah__item" id="list_item_1_2">
    bbb
   </a>
    <a href="" class="wadah__item" id="list_item_1_3">
    ccc
   </a>
    <a href="" class="wadah__item" id="list_item_1_4">
    ddd
   </a>
    <a href="" class="wadah__item" id="list_item_1_5">
    eee
   </a>
    <a href="" class="wadah__item" id="list_item_1_6">
    fff
   </a>
    <div id="loadMore" class="LoadMore">Load more 1</div>
  </div>

  <div class="wadah" id="list_2">
    <a href="" class="wadah__item" id="list_item_2_1">
    2_a
   </a>

    <a href="" class="wadah__item" id="list_item_2_2">
    2_b
   </a>
    <a href="" class="wadah__item" id="list_item_2_3">
    2_c
   </a>
    <a href="" class="wadah__item" id="list_item_2_4">
    2_d
   </a>
    <a href="" class="wadah__item" id="list_item_2_5">
    2_e
   </a>
    <a href="" class="wadah__item" id="list_item_2_6">
    2_f
   </a>

    <div id="loadMore" class="LoadMore">Load more 2</div>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

---

**UPDATE :** You can even show first 2 elements by using CSS instead of jQuery code.

```
.wadah .wadah__item:nth-child(-n + 2){
   display : flex;
}
```

```js
$(function() {


  $(".LoadMore").on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $(this).parent().find(".wadah__item:hidden").slice(0, 2).slideDown().css('display', 'flex');

    if ($(this).parent().find(".wadah__item:hidden").length == 0) {
      $(this).fadeOut('slow');
    }

    $('html,body').animate({
      scrollTop: $(this).offset().top
    }, 2000);
  });
});
```

```css
.wadah {
  margin: 30px 0;
}

.wadah__item {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-top: none;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.wadah__item {
  display: none;
}

#loadMore {
  color: green;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#loadMore:hover {
  color: black;
}

#showLess {
  color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
}

#showLess:hover {
  color: black;
}

.wadah .wadah__item:nth-child(-n + 2) {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wadah" id="list_1">
    <a href="" class="wadah__item" id="list_item_1_1">
    aaa
   </a>

    <a href="" class="wadah__item" id="list_item_1_2">
    bbb
   </a>
    <a href="" class="wadah__item" id="list_item_1_3">
    ccc
   </a>
    <a href="" class="wadah__item" id="list_item_1_4">
    ddd
   </a>
    <a href="" class="wadah__item" id="list_item_1_5">
    eee
   </a>
    <a href="" class="wadah__item" id="list_item_1_6">
    fff
   </a>
    <div id="loadMore" class="LoadMore">Load more 1</div>
  </div>

  <div class="wadah" id="list_2">
    <a href="" class="wadah__item" id="list_item_2_1">
    2_a
   </a>

    <a href="" class="wadah__item" id="list_item_2_2">
    2_b
   </a>
    <a href="" class="wadah__item" id="list_item_2_3">
    2_c
   </a>
    <a href="" class="wadah__item" id="list_item_2_4">
    2_d
   </a>
    <a href="" class="wadah__item" id="list_item_2_5">
    2_e
   </a>
    <a href="" class="wadah__item" id="list_item_2_6">
    2_f
   </a>

    <div id="loadMore" class="LoadMore">Load more 2</div>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`siblings()`](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) and only select from siblings of the button click

```
$(function () {
        $(".wadah__item").slice(0, 2).slideDown().css('display', 'flex');
        $(".LoadMore").on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
          let sibs = $(this).siblings(".wadah__item:hidden");
            sibs.slice(0, 2).slideDown().css('display', 'flex');

            if (sibs.length == 0) {
                $(this).fadeOut('slow');
            }

            $('html,body').animate({
                scrollTop: $(this).offset().top
            }, 2000);
        });
    });
```